# Можно ли прочитать значения в массиве после заполнения функцией в DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Допустим у меня есть DLL с функцией FillArray() и в DLL есть public static поле FilledArray. FillArray() заполняет FilledArray. Можно ли прочитать из приложения, которое вызвало функцию FillArray(), поле FilledArray?

Comment: Если оно имеет модификатор public легко, если нет то через рефлексию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы подключили dll и поле в сборке объявленно как public, то вы будете иметь к нему точно такой же доступ как и к методу FillArray. Правда говорят что публичные поля это плохой стиль.